# Making $ |1 - e^{i\langle t,x-y\rangle}| \leq \varepsilon $

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $t, x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Why does it hold that for fixed $t$ and $\forall \varepsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $\forall x,y: |x-y| < \delta$ it follows

$$
|1 - e^{i\langle t,x-y\rangle}| \leq \varepsilon \text{?}
$$

I tried to reason in the following way:

Since $|1-e^{i\varphi}|= \sqrt{2(1-\cos{\varphi})}$, then by making $\varphi$ closer to $0$, i.e. $|\varphi| < \delta$ one should be able to make it as small as needed. But how can this be extended to the above case by varying $\langle t,x-y\rangle$? Or maybe there is a better approach?

Comment: $$ \begin{align} \text{right: } & \qquad \langle t,x-y\rangle \\ \text{wrong: } & \qquad <t,x-y> \end{align} $$ I edited accordingly. Just google "latex symbols" when you need things like this. (This software is MathJax, not LaTeX, but most of the mathematical notation is coded the same way.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\vert \varphi \vert := \vert \langle t, x- y \rangle \vert \leq \vert t \vert \vert x -y\vert < \vert t \vert \delta$.

BTW: It should be $\sqrt{2(1 - \cos \varphi )}$.